# Searching For Articles API

Tags: javascript, php, asp.net, json

I am working on a project that shows article from different sources like  Wikipedia,Google etc my question is that is there any API ? that give me JSON type Data for article. i found this MediaWiki API but not enough for my project. Thanks In advance

Comment: What you mean by saying 'not enough for my project' ? what you want ? please be clear.

Comment: Why don't  you write a scrapper yourself so you can scrap from all website you want

Comment: Please be more clear. Also, if you didn't find anything by googling, chances are that you will need to write your own.

Comment: I mean only Wikipedia is not enough i want to show more articles on my web from other sources.

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for news articles I can really recommend the News API: https://newsapi.org/ 
It is a very simple RESTful API which responses in JSON. But it just returns the Header and a short description of the article and a link which references the articles Website for further interest.

If that's not what you were looking for, than I can really recommend searching for APIs on the ProgrammableWeb: https://www.programmableweb.com/
 It is like an library where you can look through a great amount of APIs and their characteristics.